# Multiple autocompletes on same form in socialengine

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, socialengine

I am quite new to socialegine module development. I want to use multiple autocomplets on my one form. I have no problem of showing multiple auto completes but problem comes when one selects options from auto complete.

I have seen that autocompet.js uses id `toValues` to show selected option from autocomlte. So if there is only one autocomplete on one form then we can have one element as `toValues` to show the selected value. But if we have multiple auto completes then how to show the selected item of each auto complete as separately? Using the following code for autocomplete

```
 en4.core.runonce.add(function() {

  new Autocompleter.Request.JSON('to', '<?php echo $this->url(array('module' => 'localspots', 'controller' => 'lookup', 'action' => 'city'), 'default', true) ?>', {
    'minLength': 2,
    'delay' : 1,
    'selectMode': 'pick',
    'autocompleteType': 'message',
    'multiple': false,
    'className': 'message-autosuggest',
    'filterSubset' : true,
    'tokenFormat' : 'object',
    'tokenValueKey' : 'label',
    'injectChoice': function(token){
      console.log(token.type);
      var choice = new Element('li', {'class': 'autocompleter-choices', 'html': token.photo, 'id':token.label});
      new Element('div', {'html': this.markQueryValue(token.label),'class': 'autocompleter-choice'}).inject(choice);
      this.addChoiceEvents(choice).inject(this.choices);
      choice.store('autocompleteChoice', token);
    },
    onPush : function(){
      if( $('toValues').value.split(',').length >= maxRecipients ){
        $('to').disabled = true;
        $('to').setAttribute("class", "disabled");     
      }
    },
  });

});
```

Comment: Did you get the solution ...?